# Returning values from functions when efficiency matters

Tags: bash

It seems to me, there are several ways to return a value from a Bash function.

**Approach 1**: Use a "local-global" variable, which is defined as `local` in the caller:

```
func1() {
    a=10
}

parent1() {
    local a

    func1
    a=$(($a + 1))
}
```

**Approach 2**: Use command substitution:

```
func2() {
    echo 10
}

parent2() {
    a=$(func2)
    a=$(($a + 1))
}
```

How much speedup could one expect from using approach 1 over approach2?

And, I know that it is not good programming practice to use global variables like in approach 1, but could it at some point be justified due to efficiency considerations?

Comment: Try running benchmarks?

Comment: Yes, approach 1 seems to be approx 33 times faster on my Ubuntu laptop :)

Comment: When efficiency matters, you stop using `bash` (or any flavor of `sh`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The single most expensive operation in shell scripting is forking. Any operation involving a fork, such as command substitution, will be 1-3 orders of magnitude slower than one that doesn't.

For example, here's a straight forward approach for a loop that reads a bunch of generated files on the form of `file-1234` and strips out the `file-` prefix using `sed`, requiring a total of three forks (command substitution + two stage pipeline):

```
$ time printf "file-%s\n" {1..10000} |
     while read line; do n=$(echo "$line" | sed -e "s/.*-//"); done

real    0m46.847s
```

Here's a loop that does the same thing with parameter expansion, requiring no forks:

```
$ time printf "file-%s\n" {1..10000} |
     while read line; do n=${line#*-}; done

real    0m0.150s
```

The forky version takes 300x longer.

Therefore, the answer to your question is yes: if efficiency matters, you have solid justification for factoring out or replacing forky code.

When the fork count is constant with respect to the input (or it's too messy to make it constant), and the code is still too slow, that's when you should rewrite it in a faster language.

Answer (score 1):

surely approach 1 is much faster than approach 2 because it has not any interrupt (which in turn may need several OS kernel crossing to service) and has only one memory access!!!