# Slow text parsing in bash script, any advice?

Tags: bash

I have wrote a script below to parse a text file that effectively removes line returns. It will take input that looks like this:

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:135            SVR         LISTENING       776
  RpcSs
```

And return this to a new text document

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:135            SVR         LISTENING       776  RpcSs
```

Some entries span more than two lines so I was not able to write a script that removes the line return from every other line so I came up with this approach below. It worked fine for small collects but a 7MB collect resulted in my computer running out of memory and it took quite a bit of time do this before it failed. I'm curious why it ran out of memory as well as hoping someone could educate me on a better way to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# VARS
writeOuput="" 
#
while read line
do 

curLine=$line                   #grab current line from document
varWord=$(echo $curLine | awk '{print $1}')     #grab first word from each line 
if [ "$varWord" == "TCP" ] || [ "$varWord" == "UDP" ]; then
    #echo "$curLine" >> results.txt
    unset writeOutput   
    writeOutput=$curLine
elif [ "$varWord" == "Active" ]; then           #new session
    printf "\n" >> results1.txt
    printf "New Session" >> results1.txt
    printf "\n" >> results1.txt
else
    writeOutput+=" $curLine"
    #echo "$writeOutput\n"  
    printf "$writeOutput\n" >> results1.txt 
    #sed -e '"$index"s/$/"$curLine"'
fi

done < $1
```

Comment: I don't see anything here that should use up that much memory or take quite that long (but looping line-by-line in the shell isn't very fast). Doing all of this with `awk` itself is likely to be faster you could also avoid collecting a buffer by outputting the newlines *before* lines instead of after them and not doing that on the lines that need to be collapsed. Also using `done < $1 > results1.txt` and not using it on every print is likely going to be faster.

Comment: The assignment and use of `$curLIne` is unnecessary, use `$line` directly. This will not affect performance much though.

Comment: You are doing exactly what [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29720548/1899640) uses as an example of slow and inefficient shell scripting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider replacing the line with the `awk` call with this line:

```
varWord=${curLine%% *}          #grab first word from each line
```

This saves the fork that happens in each iteration by using Bash-internal functionality only and should make your program run several times faster. See also that other guy's comment linking to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29720548/1899640) for an explanation.

Comment: This splits from the first space. If there is a space before the first word, it will return an empty string.

Comment: @chw21: Yes, but `$curLine` never contains a leading space as `read` performs word splitting and strips delimiters - type `help read` for more on this.

Comment: I am testing this now, it is significantly faster than my solution and I learned a new Bash trick, I wasn't familiar with before.

${parameter%%word}
The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the main bottleneck in your script is probably the forking where you pass each line through its own `awk` instance.

I have created an `awk` script which I hope does the same as your `bash` script, and I suspect it should run faster. Initially I just thought about replacing newlines with spaces, and manually adding newlines in front of every `TCP` or `UDP`, like this:

```
awk '
    BEGIN          {ORS=" "}; 
    $1~/(TCP|UDP)/ {printf("\n")}; 
                   {print}; 
    END            {printf("\n")}
' <file>
```

But your script removes the 'Active' lines from the output, and adds three new lines **before** the line. You could, of course, pipe this through a second `awk command:

```
awk '/Active/ {gsub(/Active /, ""); print("\nNew Session\n")}; {print}'
```

But this `awk` script is a bit closer to what you did with `bash`, but it should still be considerably faster:

```
$ cat join.awk
$1~/Active/    {print("\nNew Session\n"); next}
$1~/(TCP|UDP)/ {if (output) print output; output = ""}
               {if (output) output = output " " $0; else output = $0}
END            {print output}

$ awk -f join.awk <file>
```

First, it checks whether the line begins with the word "Active", if it does, it prints the three lines, and goes on to the next input line.

Otherwise it checks for the presence of `TCP` or `UDP` as the first word. If it finds them, it prints what has accumulated in `writeOutput` (provided there is something in the variable), and clears it.
It then adds whatever it finds in the line to `writeOutput`

At the end, it prints what has accumulated since the last `TCP` or `UDP`.

Comment: Inspired by your comment on my solution ;-) I've tested `join.awk` with the input provided by the OP, with one leading space inserted. It behaves differently in that it does not remove leading spaces from the input as the OP's (and my modified) Bash script does. It will of course be much faster (about 10 times faster than my solution for a file with 100 times the OP's sample input, my solution in turn is almost 20 times faster than the original).

Comment: This worked really well, thanks! I'm not well versed in the use of awk so I am still going through your response as it does what I need it to but when combining lines the delimiter appears to be different than the delimiter used on each line. I can fix this by importing it into Excel but once I develop a bit more familiarity with what's going on I'm sure I can change it to do this without Excel. It is magnitudes faster and I sincerely appreciate your advice!